Syntax error when trying to execute Python script to burn efuse on ESP32 board
I own an ESP32 board (Lilygo TTGO T-Display).
I'd like to burn the internal efuses that select the interval voltage so I always have a 3.3V regulator.
This is explained here:
Note about GPIO12
I have downlaoded and installed everything.
When I run the command:
python3 components/esptool_py/esptool/espefuse.py set_flash_voltage 3.3V

I get:
components/esptool_py/esptool/espefuse.py: line 7: import: command not found
components/esptool_py/esptool/espefuse.py: line 8: import: command not found
components/esptool_py/esptool/espefuse.py: line 11: syntax error near unexpected token `subprocess.run'
components/esptool_py/esptool/espefuse.py: line 11: `    sys.exit(subprocess.run([sys.executable, '-m', 'espefuse'] + sys.argv[1:]).returncode)'

With this command :
python3 -m  espefuse set_flash_voltage 3.3V 

I get :
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<frozen runpy>", line 198, in _run_module_as_main
  File "<frozen runpy>", line 88, in _run_code
  File "/Users/benjaminghedini/esp/esp-idf/components/esptool_py/esptool/espefuse.py", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(subprocess.run([sys.executable, '-m', 'espefuse'] + sys.argv[1:]).returncode)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/subprocess.py", line 548, in run
    with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as process:
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/subprocess.py", line 1026, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/subprocess.py", line 1885, in _execute_child
    self.pid = _fork_exec(
               ^^^^^^^^^^^
BlockingIOError: [Errno 35] Resource temporarily unavailable

Here's the espefuse.py file:
#
# SPDX-FileCopyrightText: 2022 Espressif Systems (Shanghai) CO LTD
#
# SPDX-License-Identifier: Apache-2.0
#

import subprocess
import sys

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.exit(subprocess.run([sys.executable, '-m', 'espefuse'] + sys.argv[1:]).returncode)

I have read the documentations three times, downloaded and installed everything needed.
What am I doing wrong?

What you have is a Python script, but you're trying to run it as a shell script.  Try python components/esptool_py/esptool/espefuse.py set_flash_voltage 3.3V .

Sorry but I made a mistake this is what I ran : 'python3 components/esptool_py/esptool/espefuse.py set_flash_voltage 3.3V' I edited the initial post

I'm sorry to say that I don't believe you.  The errors above are from bash, not from Python.

How are you expecting this to do anything to your ESP32?  It's just trying to re-execute itself, with the same parameters.

@jasonharper I'm trying to burn an efuse. Everything is explained on the link above.

@TimRoberts you must be right because I'm new to Pyhton. In fact I'm just trying to execute the command that is given in the link above. So I open a terminal window and run the command given above with "python3' at the beginning. I'll include a screenshot

And does python3 -m espefuse set_flash_voltage 3.3V work?

Nope, initial post edited with results
